# AppBarLayout is not responding to scroll in the fragment

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I am using the new Android Support Design library. I have followed the demo on the Android Developer Blogspot except I use a fragment for RecyclerView instead of putting both in the same xml.

Here's my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/container"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:name="aungkyawpaing.yangonuniversity.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|left"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


And this is the fragment where it has RecyclerView

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/department_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

I have add latest support library dependency in gradle. I have seen another person saying it doesn't work because he used list view in the fragment, but I'm using RecyclerView as suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, this might looks stupid But you have to add this in dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

Your FrameLayout need to be wrapped by a NestedScrollView because FrameLayout doesn't handle Behaviour class.